# How to filter MIDI output from a Yamaha P-45 keyboard in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, midi

Currently I'm writing a python script that accepts output from a keyboard, a Yamaha P-45. My goal is for each note played on keyboard to be compared to notes stored in a text file and mark the ones that are wrong (for example: when playing a piece of some kind, it would show where you made mistakes).

 
As of now it prints any note or pedal events, though in the future I would like it to store them in the form of

```
[note, on/off, velocity, tone, time]       #for notes    
[pedal, on/off, time]                      #for pedal
```

The problem is that the keyboard is sending out what I think is the keyboard's clock
Like so:

```
[[248, 0, 0, 0], 1497]
[[248, 0, 0, 0], 1518]
[[248, 0, 0, 0], 1538]
[[248, 0, 0, 0], 1559]
[[248, 0, 0, 0], 1580]
[[248, 0, 0, 0], 1601]
[[248, 0, 0, 0], 1622]
```

My question is, how do I filter out the timing midi events? Is there a way to directly filter any midi events other than note and pedal events? I feel like just having  a bunch of ifs is not the best solution 
A shortened version of my script:

```
midi.init()
midiId = 1               #id of my keyboard
midi_out = midi.Input(midiId)

try:                  #  try finally for ctrl-cing 

    t0 = time.clock()                    #define beginning time
    while True:                                   #begin main loop
        for f in midi_out.read(10):                                 
        #the events gets read in nested list [[status, numbers, numbers numbers . . .] time]

            print(f)

finally:
    midi_out.close()
    midi.quit()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: At the moment, it prints *all* events. Just ignore those you are not interested in. Do you actually know what MIDI messages are?

Comment: @CL. So then should I have something in the form of if f[0][0] == 144: listwithnotes.append(f)? Wouldn't that be kind of inefficient, since it would check at each event whether it's a note?

Comment: Inefficient compared to what? You need to get it correct before you can think about optimizing it.